# How to set initial value for auto incremented property (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class called **Offer** as follows:

```
public class Offer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OfferNo { get; set; }

    public OfferType OfferType { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateAdded { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateEdited { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I am using **Id** property as my PK obviously. But I also need to display the Id of offers (as users will search for offers using this value) and the Guid property is too long for that.

Thus, I tried to use DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity to auto increment the integer column **OfferNo**, but I can not set an initial value to increment on. I inserted a dummy entry and then tried to set **OfferNo** to something else than 1, but received the following exception:

**Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'OfferNo'. Table: 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Offer'.**

I would like to set the initial value of this auto incremented column using code-first. An alternative solution will also be appreciated.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732102/how-do-i-set-identity-seed-on-an-id-column-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-w

Comment: @DavidBrabant Unfortunately this is not a code-first approach and I know so little about SQL.

Comment: Why do you need the `Guid` if you're also creating an identity column?

Comment: @DavidG I use Guid as PKs all around in my application. In my application, users should be able to search for offers using an Id and I can't expect them to type GUIDs in a textbox. Using an integer PK will not solve the problem I mentioned above, because I don't want to have Ids with couple of digits.

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi I've fully rewritten my answer. Please, let me know if I can make it even more clear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the comment, "but starting from a seed value that I provide instead of 1", you can use an identity column, and customize your database initialization or migration to set the seed of your identity column.

The T-SQL command to do this is:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Offer', RESEED, 123);
```

**Note** *that the next inserted value is not 123, but 123 + increment (124 if default increment of 1).*

You can also use a column with the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` and a [sequence as default value for your field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413383/sequence-as-default-value-for-a-column) (if you're using a recent SQL server version). When you [create a sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx), you can specify the initial value and increment:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE OfferNoSeq
START WITH 1 -- Initial Value
INCREMENT BY 1 -- Increment
```

An attach this sequence as a default for the `OfferNo` column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Offer ADD CONSTRAINT OfferNoSeq 
DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR OfferNoSeq)  FOR OfferNo;
```

There is no direct way to implement this in Code First. So, for using any of these options, you need to

- [customize the DB initialization](http://omerc.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/entity-framework-code-first-data.html) This is done by implementing your own database initializer class and execute the desired SQL commands from the `Seed` methods (look for the implementation of `public class MyInitializer` in the linked article)
- or to [customize a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731889/add-database-trigger-with-entity-framework-code-first-migrations): you can execute any SQL Command in the `Up()` or `Down()` method of your migration, as shown in the linked SO answer

Please, if you use SEQUENCE, please, read this: [EF6 does not work with primary key from sequence](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/165).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I learnt more than I requested :) I actually applied my own solution which is using the auto incremented field that starts from 1 and add/subtract a fixed number in the application to produce the seeded value. I also tried the 'customizing the DB initialization' and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: putting a `DBCC CHECKIDENT` in my initializer.. SIMPLE and PERFECT.

Comment: RE: the note about the next inserted value, I'm finding that if I'm initializing my `(localdb)\v11.0` that the next value is not always incremented. E.g. if I set my `Locations` table to have an `id` seeded with `0`, the initial record that I insert does not have a `1`, but actually starts with a `0`

Answer (score 13):

Just found a solution for this matter. You can simply call a Sql() method in your Up() method.

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "Offers",
            c => new
                {
                    OfferNo = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ...
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.OfferNo);
        Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Offers', RESEED, 100);");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that for sure. But at the moment, I don't have an override for `Up` method in migrations. Do you think I can reseed Offers table right after initialization?

Comment: Seems to be the simplest solution by far

Comment: I can't seem to make this work in my Azure, only on my `(localdb)\v11.0`

Comment: @Simon_Weaver-  I wanted some entity tables in my Azure SQL Database to start with an `Id` set to `0`. I never found a repeatable way to do this via my "Publish.." button in Visual Studio when refreshing my Web API. I gave up on the idea. It wasn't worth my effort. I vaguely recall that it sometimes worked, but, for some reason wasn't repeatable/reliable

Comment: Hi, What is the rollback query ?

Comment: @AdelMourad - I guess DropTable() is a goog candidate, but it will depend on your implementation. If you created the table in Up you should drop it in Down.
If you just need to bump the Autoincrement in Up you can Delete all the records above this Id...
Again, it might depend on the scenario you have...

Comment: Thanks for replying but i was wondering if i can just set the auto increment back to start from 0 when i do not have data in the table, maybe this will work i will test it later DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Offers', RESEED, 0);   ...