# Where can I execute Raw SQL Code when deploying Db?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I described the database through Fluent Api.

However, I want to use `Database.EnsureCreated ();` some additional SQL code was executed.

Where can i place it?

Comment: You can place it anywhere that is in-scope of the calling code.  Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: In other words, find a place to put the code, put it in an appropriate namespace, add the necessary `using` statements, and call it like you would call any other method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You understood not quite right.
I want that if the database was absent when creating the context, then Database.EnsureCreated (); it was created + executed by some SQL code. Can I override any DbContext method to achieve the goal?

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you are asking.  If you just want to execute your own SQL though EF core, [this explains how to do that.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Some like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731889/add-database-trigger-with-entity-framework-code-first-migrations

Comment: Why doesn't that post answer your question?